# How to properly use njit/jit in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program for value function iteration, and I want to utilize the nopython mode from numba library. The code below doesn't really do anything(I wanted to start from the beginning to understand where I am making a mistake). It should just return the matrices I create in the function. The inputs in the function are needed for optimization that I would do later. However, I am facing the error(please see below).

I tried using @njit and also @jit that includes specific type I use for each inputs. However, both do not work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
import time
from datetime import timedelta
from numba import jit, njit, int32, float64
from gridlookup import gridlookup


beta = 0.99322 
sigma = 1.5
enum = 2
egrid = np.array([0.1, 1.0])
pie = np.array([[0.5, 0.5], 
                [0.075, 0.925]])
blow = -2.0; bhigh = 4.0; bnum = 10
bgrid = np.logspace(np.log(blow + -1.0*blow + 1.0)/np.log(10.0), np.log(bhigh + -1.0*blow + 1.0)/np.log(10.0), bnum)
bgrid = bgrid + np.ones(np.shape(bgrid))*(blow - 1.0)
mubgnum = 1000
mubgrid = np.linspace(blow, bhigh, mubgnum)

v0 = np.array(np.zeros((enum,bnum)))

@njit
def vfini(bnum, enum, bgrid, egrid, v0):
    ## calculate the initial value function.
    for i in range(bnum):
        bval = bgrid[i]
        for m in range(enum):
            eval0 = egrid[m]
            yval = 0.025*bval + eval0
            v0[m,i] = (yval**(1-sigma))/(1.0-sigma)

    return v0

v0 = vfini(bnum, enum, bgrid, egrid, v0)

@jit([(int32, float64[:], float64[:,:], float64, float64, int32,
        float64[:], int32, float64[:], float64, float64[:,:],float64)],nopython=True)
def huggettqegm(enum, egrid, pie, beta, sigma, bnum, 
                bgrid, mubgnum, mubgrid, precision, v0, q):

    v_I = np.array(np.zeros((enum,bnum)))
    g_I = np.array(np.zeros((enum,bnum)))
    tv_I = np.array(np.zeros((enum,bnum))) 
    tg_I = np.array(np.zeros((enum,bnum)))

    return v_I, g_I

q = qlow

v, g = huggettqegm(enum, egrid, pie, beta, sigma, bnum, bgrid, mubgnum, mubgrid, precision, v0, q)
```

The below is the error message when I run the simple code above:

> TypingError: Invalid use of Function() with
>   argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 2d, C))  * parameterized In
>   definition 0:
>       TypingError: array(float64, 2d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence
>       raised from C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\npydecl.py:460 In
>   definition 1:
>       TypingError: array(float64, 2d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence
>       raised from C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\npydecl.py:460 This error
>   is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported
>   by the named function. [1] During: resolving callee type:
>   Function() [2] During: typing of call at
>   C:/Users/Jung Hwan
>   Kim/Dropbox/StudentDebtCrisis/Program/Python/July012019/practice.py
>   (124)

I thought I could use the numpy to create the array and use them in the njit mode. Or maybe I am misunderstanding the basic use of njit.. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: The `np.array(` in `np.array(np.zeros((enum,bnum)))` is completely useless and obivously not supported. (np.zeros already allocates an array filled with zeros). The type declaration is false (int64 instead of int32). Anyway the typedeclaration is normally not necessary and can often reduce performance (eg. declaring explicitely a non contigous array)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not know that np.array is not supported. Do you recommend to use @njit instead of declaring types by using @jit? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @njit is just a shortcut for @jit(nopython=True). In normal jit mode, Numba detects the datatypes and memorylayout itself, at best you get the same speed if you declare it manually. You only need this if you use AOT compilation https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning about numba.

In general, to begin with this is better to leave the decorators by default.
However, I've seen some topics.

1. Create an empty bumpy array with np.empty.
   Example

```py
v0 = np.empty((enum, bnum))
```

- for better performance you may declare the datatype

```py
v0 = np.empty((enum, bnum), dtype=np.float64)
```

2. There is not the precision and q variables

### For simplicity I will use the first 4 variables in your  huggettgegm function

```py
@jit([(int32, float64[:], float64[:,:], float64, )], nopython=True)
def huggettqegm(enum, egrid, pie, beta,):

    v_I = np.empty((enum, bnum), dtype=np.float64)
    g_I = np.empty((enum, bnum), dtype=np.float64)


    return v_I, g_I


v, g = huggettqegm(enum, egrid, pie, beta,)
```

The problem was in the output data type, when yo create a np.array numpy analyze the values and take a default data type, as you need an empty list is better use np.empty and declare the datatype as you like, and later change the value.

[numpy empty](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html)